# How do i define a list without adding any values?

Tags: python, list

I have written a piece of code that for a 21 card trick homework:

```
def random_list():
        suits = ["D","S","C","h"]
        cardnumbers = ["A",2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,"J","Q","K"]
        point1 = point = m = 0
        List1 = []
        List2 = []
        List3 = []
        listnames = [List1], [List2], [List3]
        while point < 3:
                y = listnames[m]
                m = m + 1
                while point1 < 7:
                        randomsuite = random.randint(0,3)
                        randomnumber = random.randint(0,11)
                        x = cardnumbers[randomnumber],suits[randomsuite];
                        y.append(x)
                        point1 = point1 + 1 
                point = point + 1 
                point1 = 0
        return listnames
```

This prints:

```
list1 = [[], (6, 'h'), (4, 'S'), (4, 'D'), (7, 'h'), ('A', 'D'), ('Q', 'D'), (9, 'C')]
list2 = [[], ('J', 'C'), ('A', 'h'), ('K', 'S'), (7, 'D'), (9, 'h'), (7, 'C'), ('A', 'h')]
list3 = [[], (6, 'C'), (4, 'h'), (5, 'D'), ('J', 'D'), (2, 'S'), (4, 'h'), (8, 'S')]
```

the first value of each of the lists is "[]" which is ruining the rest of the code. I have tried removing the value from the list afterwards but, it has this error***'tuple' object has no attribute 'remove'***
Thanks

Comment: You want `listnames = [List1, List2, List3]` - a single 3-element list, not a tuple of three 1-element lists.

Comment: Incidentally, the singular of "suits" is "suit", not "suite". And why are you using `while` loops instead of `for` loops?

Comment: i don't really know how to use for loops and thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were very close: simply had to put the three list into listnames

```
import random
def random_list():
        suits = ["D","S","C","h"]
        cardnumbers = ["A",2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,"J","Q","K"]
        point1 = point = m = 0
        List1 = []
        List2 = []
        List3 = []
        listnames = [List1, List2, List3]
        while point < 3:
                y = listnames[m]
                m = m + 1
                while point1 < 7:
                        randomsuite = random.randint(0,3)
                        randomnumber = random.randint(0,11)
                        x = cardnumbers[randomnumber],suits[randomsuite];
                        y.append(x)
                        point1 = point1 + 1
                point = point + 1
                point1 = 0
        return listnames

list1, list2, list3 = random_list()
print "list1: ", list1
print "list2: ", list2
print "list3: ", list3
```

---

```
list1:  [('A', 'S'), ('Q', 'C'), (2, 'S'), ('K', 'D'), (7, 'h'), (4, 'C'), ('A', 'S')]
list2:  [(5, 'D'), (6, 'h'), ('J', 'h'), (8, 'h'), ('J', 'S'), ('A', 'D'), (2, 'h')]
list3:  [(7, 'S'), (7, 'C'), (8, 'D'), ('A', 'C'), (5, 'h'), (2, 'D'), (9, 'S')]
```

Answer (score 0):

you should just construct `listnames` as a list include `List1` and `List2` and `List3` so like this `listsnames = [List1, List2, List3]`

BUT (not sure why you want to make a three elements tuple list) if you really wish to make a three elements tuple list you can just remove `[]` at the end. If `[]` is always at the start then just do a clean up before you return the `listnames`

```
def random_list():
        suits = ["D","S","C","h"]
        cardnumbers = ["A",2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,"J","Q","K"]
        point1 = point = m = 0
        List1 = []
        List2 = []
        List3 = []
        listnames = [List1], [List2], [List3]
        while point < 3:
                y = listnames[m]
                m = m + 1
                while point1 < 7:
                        randomsuite = random.randint(0,3)
                        randomnumber = random.randint(0,11)
                        x = cardnumbers[randomnumber],suits[randomsuite];
                        y.append(x)
                        point1 = point1 + 1 
                point = point + 1 
                point1 = 0
        for x in range(0, len(listnames)):  #clean up here
          listnames[x].pop(0)
        return listnames
```

print it:

```
print(random_list()[0])
print(random_list()[1])
print(random_list()[2])
```

result

```
[(9, 'D'), (8, 'C'), ('J', 'h'), (9, 'h'), (2, 'D'), (3, 'C'), (3, 'S')]
[(3, 'S'), (2, 'h'), (2, 'S'), (2, 'D'), (4, 'D'), (9, 'D'), ('Q', 'C')]
[('Q', 'C'), ('K', 'S'), (4, 'h'), (3, 'D'), ('Q', 'S'), (6, 'C'), ('J', 'S')]
```

Answer (score 0):

This loop is a problem:

```
 while point1 < 7:
    randomsuite = random.randint(0,3)
    randomnumber = random.randint(0,11)
    x = cardnumbers[randomnumber],suits[randomsuite];
    y.append(x)
    point1 = point1 + 1
```

As it lets you deal the same card twice (not nice in a friendly game.)  You can see this in your `list2` output where `('A', 'h')` appears twice.  Let's fix this, and your original problem, and simplify your code in the process:

```
from random import choice

def random_list(deals_per_list=3, cards_per_deal=7):
    suits = ["D", "S", "C", "H"]
    cardnumbers = ["A", 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, "J", "Q", "K"]

    list_of_deals = []
    for _ in range(deals_per_list):
            list_of_deals.append([])

    for deal in list_of_deals:
        while len(deal) < cards_per_deal:
            card = (choice(suits), choice(cardnumbers))
            if card not in deal:
                deal.append(card)

    return list_of_deals

deals = random_list()

for n, deal in enumerate(deals, start=1):
    print("deal{}".format(n), deal)
```

Comment: i have fixed that now but not in the same way. I used a different function to create an entire deck then another that randomly picked out and deleted to avoid getting the same card twice. thanks